# Regex find and replace with characters that can vary

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to write a line in a bash script that takes all instances of pushing and popping a register and changes it from the 32-bit register to the 64-bit register.  For example, `push ecx` Should become `push rcx`

The only character that can vary is the second to last one, so finding with `e\wx` works fine, but how do I make it so that whatever character is found in \w is kept, as well as whichever, of the push/pop is present?  The only character that needs to change is the e to an r.

In short, I have this:

```
 sed -i -e "s/push eax/push rax/"
 sed -i -e "s/push ebx/push rbx/"
 sed -i -e "s/push ecx/push rcx/"
 sed -i -i "s/push edx/push rdx/"
 sed -i -e "s/pop eax/pop rax/"
 sed -i -e "s/pop ebx/pop rbx/"
 sed -i -e "s/pop ecx/pop rcx/"
 sed -i -i "s/pop edx/pop rdx/"
```

And I want to know if I can do it in one line

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
sed -i 's/\(push\|pop\) r\([abcd]\)x/\1 e\2x/'
```

Sample run :

```
$ echo """push rax
push rbx
push rcx
push rdx
pop rax
pop rbx
pop rcx
pop rdx
nop""" | sed 's/\(push\|pop\) r\([abcd]\)x/\1 e\2x/'
push eax
push ebx
push ecx
push edx
pop eax
pop ebx
pop ecx
pop edx
nop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture group:

```
sed -i -e "s/(push|pop) e(\w+)/\\1 r\\2/"
```

I don't have a console handy so I can't test it, you can see the [Regex stub](https://regex101.com/r/pL1cX7/2) here.